# Duplicate Cell loading in UItableview Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been stuck on this bug for the past 5 hours I Really need some help. I am making a chat application that has private messaging. When a user sends a text everything works great. But when a use trys to reply to a message another user sent , things get weird. 
[image]

the user duplicates, along with failing to update time and the most recent text! whats going on! here is the code

Message controller: loads the message users from which firebase provides I know this could have potentially been an uploading to firebase issue, where their are two children but my firebase looks fine, NO duplicates on the back end. The error ive narrowed it down to being in this class when loading these custom cells into a table view! how do i force it to stop duplicating and rather load the correct one? Thank you so much!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class MessagesViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate 
, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var messagesLabelOutlet: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var messagesTableView: UITableView!

var newUser : User?
var messageArr = [Message]()
var messageDict = [String: Message]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    messagesTableView.dataSource = self
    messagesTableView.delegate = self;
    self.messagesTableView.register(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
    messageArr.removeAll()
    messageDict.removeAll()
    messagesTableView.reloadData()
    observeUserMessages()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messageArr.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.newUser = User()

    if let chatPartnerId = messageArr[indexPath.row].chatPartnerId(){
        self.newUser?.toId! = chatPartnerId;



    let chatPartnerDataRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(chatPartnerId)

    chatPartnerDataRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] else{
            return

        }
            self.newUser?.userName = dict["username"] as? String
            self.newUser?.picURL = dict["pic"] as? String
            self.newUser?.score = dict["score"] as? String


        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: 
"goToChatLogControllerPlzFromMessages", sender: self)

    }
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! UserCell
    let message = messageArr[indexPath.row]

let totalSection = tableView.numberOfSections



    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Book" , size: 19);
    cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Light" , size: 14);


    cell.message = message;
    return cell;
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // do not remove
    if segue.identifier == "goToChatLogControllerPlzFromMessages"{
        print("going to chat log")
    let recieveVC = segue.destination as! ChatLogController

    if let textUser = newUser{
        recieveVC.user = textUser;

    }
    }

}

func checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
{

    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil{
        print("uid is nil")

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "noUserFoundGoingBackToLogin", sender: self);

    }
    else{
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        })
    }
}

func observeUserMessages(){
   print("NEW USER \(newUser?.userName)")
    print("MESSAGE ARR \(messageArr)")
    print("MESSAGE DICT\(messageDict.values)")

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{
        checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
        return;
    }

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(uid)

    ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let messageId = snapshot.key
        let messagesRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId)
        messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
            {
                let message = Message()
                message.fromId = dict["fromid"] as? String;
                message.text = dict["text"] as? String;
                message.timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? String;
                message.toId = dict["toid"] as? String;


                self.messageArr.append(message)


                if let toID = message.toId{

                    self.messageDict[toID] = message;
                    self.messageArr = Array(self.messageDict.values)
                    self.messageArr.sort(by: { (message1, message2) -> Bool in

                        let time1 = Int(truncating: (message1.timestamp?.numberValue)!)
                        let time2 = Int(truncating: (message2.timestamp?.numberValue)!)

                        return time1 > time2
                    })


                }



                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(message.text!)
                    self.messagesTableView.reloadData()
                }

            }


        })
    }
```

Comment: In all likelihood this is due to reuse of cells that have scrolled off the screen. Just make sure every member of the cell view is assigned each time you need to write a new cell, including members that you weren't expecting to edit.

Comment: is your `messageArr` correct ?

Comment: how would i do that @Carlos ? thanks for the suggestion

Comment: messageArr stores all the message objects which contain toid , fromid , text and time. messageArr does what its suppose to do , there are no duplicates in there as i have printed it out several times to make sure @GIJOW thanks

Comment: There's a little too much code for me to see the answer right away, but the way these table views work is you have a function that fills in the fields with your data. What also happens is when a cell goes out of view, it gets recycled. But it doesn't have those fields reset.

Comment: how would i reset those fields @Carlos ? thanks for all the help

Comment: Well where are you telling the program to fill in the cell? Whatever function does that should also reset the rest of the fields. Also you should just make sure that resetting is in fact the problem. The symptom is that you're seeing elements from old cells in new ones?